# How to remove edit from edit queue?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, undo

I asked a question on SO: [Unix find: list of files from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6185994/15456) and got an answer that, while good, I thought could be improved with a minor edit: [Unix find: list of files from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185994/unix-find-list-of-files-from-stdin/6186080#6186080)

After a little while, a comment on the answer showed me that I was wrong to have edited the answer.  How do I undo it?

Comment: You can flag the post for moderator attention. See reasoning here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105092/139264

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your only option is to wait for it to get rejected. Hopefully, the reviewers will notice that it is an erroneous edit and will not blindly approve it. If it does get blindly approved, suggest that the author roll it back. Also suggest that the author contribute to voting on the rejection.

As long as you didn't propose a slew of rejected edits very recently, this singular rejection should not have any true negative impact on your account.

Comment: Aww I accidentally proposed an edit when somebody edited it back. I tried to find out what that was but I got my edit approved after I edited the owner's second edit.