# Retract edit suggestions

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I came to a situation, where while I was suggesting an edit, the OP already improved it (better than my version). As this was only 1-2 minutes after the question was posed, OP's edit isn't even listed in the edit history. Am I able to retract my own edit, as it makes no longer sence, and would just look like an degradation?
Should I just write a short comment, explaining the issue?

Comment: @Glorfindel How can I edit the edit summary of a suggested edit?

Comment: @Glorfindel I don't think this is a duplicate. All OP's edits were already Approved when he posted this.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it's about a situation where it's still pending. But let's see ...

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser just hit the edit button again and update it.

Comment: @Glorfindel Could you post the link to the possible duplicate again? I think that was in fact my question.

Comment: It's still in the "Linked" section on the right.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser You can see it as a "linked" question in the right sidebar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93268/how-to-remove-edit-from-edit-queue?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ColleenV Operating from mobile, but I found it in the edit history.

Comment: May not be exactly the same, but answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do.

The edit is already Approved, and the OP's original improvement is lost.
If the OP's original improvement was still in the history, you could try to roll back to that revision. This option is available if you have full edit privileges (meaning 2000 rep or more). The OP can also roll back to a previous revision, as they have full control over their own posts, regardless of rep level.

If the OP is unhappy with the situation and expresses that unhappiness... well, then you can apologize. You had good intentions, there was just a rather unfortunate sequence of events.