# Can I modify and resubmit my suggested edit before it is peer reviewed?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Recently I made a suggested edit, and then after submitting the edit, I realized that I removed a keyword from the original title. Sometimes, I felt that I could have suggested a better edit than I just submitted. I don't know if I am the only one or there are more people who sometimes feel this way.

Is there a way I can cancel and re-submit or edit my own suggested edit after submitting the suggested edit, but before it is acted upon (either approved or rejected)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel an edit I made on another user answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80933/how-to-cancel-an-edit-i-made-on-another-user-answer)

Comment: But I think the answers on that thread are incomplete and [animuson's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157606) is correct, you can edit back to the old version and resubmit, and that will cancel the suggestion if it hasn't been reviewed yet.

Comment: @Gilles: I've never tested if editing back to the original version cancels the suggested edit or not. I imagine it would. But his true intent for the cancel was to make additional changes, and this method works perfectly for that. :)

Comment: @Gilles: As animuson noted, my intent was to make additional changes - but I understand someone would want to cancel their suggestion altogether. I am curious to see if what you said is how it happens. Anyhow, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your grace period actually applies to the suggested edit still being active. If it hasn't been approved or rejected yet, you can still continue to make additional edits to it which all get collapsed into that suggestion; just click the edit button again and the box will fill with the edit you suggested. Just make sure if you make any major changes you modify the edit reason so that you don't confuse the heck out of those reviewing it. I've done this before, myself, when I noticed a misspelling in some text I added.

On most of the smaller sites, it can take some time for edits to get approved/rejected, giving you ample time to correct any mistakes. However, larger sites may not get you much of a grace period for making changes to your suggestion.

Comment: I went and [tested](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10151) (FOR SCIENCE!). You can change your edit, at least as long as it hasn't been reviewed. But you can't cancel it: if you change back to the original version, the updated suggestion is rejected as too minor.

Comment: @Gilles: +1 for testing and letting us know about the canceling.