# View edit review queue, remove own suggested edits from queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I realized I'd made a bad edit on Electrical Engineering SE right after I submitted the edit and I felt awful about it.  By now, I'm sure its been denied but I really didn't like that I couldn't do a thing about it.

I'd edited the answer based off of the accepted answer and it turns out that it was proven wrong in the comments, which I should have read in retrospect.

Either way, I feel like when you gain the ability to suggest an edit, you should be able to at least see your edit in the review queue with the option to remove it from the queue, should you find it to be wrong.

Comment: While this would be a great feature to implement, in the meantime you can [overwrite your edit with something better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80933/how-can-i-cancel-an-edit-i-made-on-another-users-question-or-answer/308972#308972) in order to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Gilles's answer, i did the same thing here on MSE. I suggested [an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31954), and a couple minutes later, realized it was wrong. Because it hadn't yet been reviewed, i went back and edited the summary:

> Reject this edit, i just realized it's incorrect and i can edit it but not cancel it

It was rejected soon after.

This is, unfortunately, the closest you can get to canceling a suggested edit.

Answer (score 6):

The review queue isn't a logical place to find your own suggested edit. After all you won't be able to review it. You can find your suggested edits in [your profile](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/28592/funkyguy?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), in the “activity” tab, “suggestions” subtab. There's no indication of the edit's status there, you need to click through to the edit.

As long as the edit hasn't been reviewed, you can go back to the post and re-edit it. However, you cannot cancel it together. Direct edits can be withdrawn if you edit back to the original state within 5 minutes (the edit grace window), but that doesn't work for suggested edits (“Nothing appears to have changed”).

It would be nice if changing a pending suggested edit to go back to the original state instead withdrew the suggested edit.